# Synchronize application calendar with google calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, icalendar, caldav

I have a java web application where every user has own simple calendar. Now I want to add feature that user can add all events from my application into his calendar, for example google calendar, but I want support Yahoo calendar too. I was trying to find some way how to do it, but I found only one lib ([caldav4j](http://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/)) which does not have any useful example or tutorial and as far as I know it uses obsolete library [slide](http://jakarta.apache.org/slide/webdav-client.html). Is there anything different what can I use?

Answer (score 2):

Google supports CalDAV (which you discovered).  You can choose only the "Google Native" API or the CalDAV API if you need Google Calendar integration.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

It is true that simple CalDAV examples are hard to find as it is a complex protocol, but it is not obsolete.  Apple and several other non-Google vendors rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Google keeps up-to date several projects providing the access to the Google Accounts data such as docs, mail, calendars and so on. You may try to look through the official docs on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
Both REST and client libraries ways are available.

Comment: I don't want use Google API because I want work with more calendars. So I don't want have a special functions for each type of calendars which I will be support.